# Local vs Member variable proper code placement

Tags: java, variables, methods

I'm still a newbie, but would like to start coding properly now, versus later. Correct me if I'm wrong, but methods should be self sufficient and independent functions of a program. So does this mean that **everything the given method needs to operate should be instantiated within that method**? I have no clue how memory operates, but if the following method is used multiple times, isn't it also theoretically creating multiple instances of it's local variables? If I ran this method 100 times, wouldn't I have 100 String variables in memory (since a string is final), as well as instantiated my scanner variable 100 times? And if I understand correctly, member variables are declared specifically for attributes of an object. The object doesn't contain the regex variable, rather refer to it, which is why I've left it out of the member variable declaration.

This method can be implemented into a class, and without hassle, operate on it's own; which from my minute understanding is the proper way to create a method.

If this is standard, then I will continue creating methods this way. Could any of you critique or expound upon member vs. local variable placement?

```
/**
 * Verifies proper phone number format.
 * @param phone 
 */
public void checkPhone(String phone)
{

    //local scanner variable***
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    //regex***
    String phoneRegex = "\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}";

    while(!phone.matches(phoneRegex))
    {
      System.out.println("You have entered an invalid phone format.");
      System.out.println("Proper format example: 123-999-1234");
      System.out.print("Re-enter phone number: ");
      phone = in.nextLine();

    }

    this.mPhoneNumber = phone;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) This question is far too broad, and probably also too opinion-based, for SO's format. *(not my downvote; I did vote to close)*

Answer (score 1):

> everything the given method needs to operate should be instantiated within that method?

It depends on the context.

If there are more methods that need the same object, you better don´t instance it multiple times for multiple methods. Just instance it once into the main class (for example).

So be careful and choose where you place and instantiate your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call checkPhone(), you create a new Scanner and regex String. As soon as the function ends, the Scanner and phoneRegex objects will be eligible for garbage collection since you do not keep a reference to them anywhere, so it is possible that there is only one instance of each them in memory at any given time. (Actually, the regex probably gets cached since it is a literal string, so it only gets created once).

However, it would be better if the Scanner and regex String were made instance variables of your class, created in the constructor instead of in checkPhone(). That way you would not incur the expense of re-creating them for each call.

As for the argument "phone", it depends on how the caller is coded as to whether there are multiple strings for multiple calls.